# Limelight Media Vault with Flash Streaming

Tags: actionscript-3, streaming, rtmp

Limelight's documentation I fear is out of date and I cannot locate anything new. I spent a good two hours with support chat yesterday asking how to get media vault working. Support told me one thing that contradicted what the documentation says.

Question is has anyone successfully played an RTMP link using their media vault system (playing media from inside the `s` folder)?

The documentation says to hash just the path from the ftp root of the server (`/aXXX/oXX/s/path/to/file`) whereas support kept telling me to hash the whole `rtmp://xxxxx.fcod.llnw.net/aXXX/oXX/s/path/to/file`

I know this question will be a long shot but I am at my wits end. I've googled countless times and cannot find out how to do this correctly.

Answer (score 1):

My team only did this for a proof of concept two years ago, so they may have changed settings but at the time we hashed the entire URL, including rtmp://.

Comment: I cant remember if I figured this out or I moved to a HTML5 media player and stuck the videos on the the static limelight servers...I am thinking the latter. Thanks for the reply though

Comment: Makes sense.  Other delivery methods which segment then deliver across pure HTTP have become more popular - Adobe itself is moving away from RTMP/RTMPe in favor of HDS/PHDS.  Cheers.